# Async task ending before all their futures are completed

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am writing an app using Flutter, and in this app, I need to call an Asynchronous Function in a button callback (`onPressed()`). The problem is that when I click the button, an exception is thrown saying that the function can't complete because the task where it is executed has already completed (before the function does). I have tried to mark the onPressed function as async and even awaiting the other asynchronous function result, but I still get the exception thrown at runtime.

What can I do in order to make the button callback wait for the asynchronous function to complete before exiting? Or how can I solve this problem?

Here is the code that's causing the problem:

```
SimpleDialogOption(child: Text('Guardar'), onPressed: () async {
                        var item = controller.text;
                        String dbparent;
                        switch (selectedFGroup) {
                          case FGroups.Azucar: dbparent = 'azucar'; break;
                          case FGroups.Cereales: dbparent = 'cereales'; break;
                          case FGroups.Frutas: dbparent = 'frutas'; break;
                          case FGroups.Grasa: dbparent = 'grasa'; break;
                          case FGroups.Leche: dbparent = 'leche'; break;
                          case FGroups.Leguminosa: dbparent = 'leguminosa'; break;
                          case FGroups.Poa: dbparent = 'poa'; break;
                          case FGroups.Verduras: dbparent = 'verduras'; break;
                          default: print('${selectedFGroup.toString()} not found, returning'); return;
                        }
                        // Update it in the local db
                        User.user.firebaseUser[dbparent][item] = false;
                        User.user.update(User.user.firebaseUser, 'firebaseUser');
                        // Update it in the Firebase backend
                        await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
                          CollectionReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
                          DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(reference.document('-LEzXx9yRMBNxOyAhHyO'));
                          await transaction.update(snapshot.reference, {'firebaseUser': User.user.firebaseUser});
                        });
                        print('addFoodItem: DONE!');
                      },),
```

And here is the log (I wasn't able to format it as a code block):

> I/FlutterActivityDelegate( 9746): onResume setting current activity to
>   this
>   E/BpSurfaceComposerClient( 9746): Failed to transact (-1)
>   E/BpSurfaceComposerClient( 9746): Failed to transact (-1)
>   I/flutter ( 9746): FGroups.Verduras
>   I/flutter ( 9746): addFoodItem: DONE!
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746): Failed to
>   handle method call result
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is already complete
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown
>   Source:8)         E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(
>   9746):      at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zzdr(Unknown Source:8)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.setResult(Unknown Source:3)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Unknown
>   Source:2)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$3$1.success(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:283)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingResultHandler.reply(MethodChannel.java:169)E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(
>   9746):      at
>   io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView.handlePlatformMessageResponse(FlutterNativeView.java:171)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 9746):      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Thanks

Comment: why are you  awaiting `FireStore.intance.runTransaction((){})`. I think you should remove the  "await" keyword preceding the runTransaction method

Comment: this is a known issue and there's no fix yet